# Optimizing djangos count() method

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework

So I have this queryset:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.query import GeoQuerySet
from django.db import models as base_models

class RestaurantsQuerySet(GeoQuerySet):
    def get_list(self, lng, lat):
        reference_point = Point(lng, lat, srid=SRID)

        return self.annotate(rating=models.Avg('comments__rating'))\
                   .annotate(distance=Distance('location', reference_point))

    def count(self):
        return self.values('id').aggregate(count=base_models.Count('id'))['count']
```

I thought that the query would look something like:

```
SELECT COUNT("__col1") 
FROM (
    SELECT "restaurants_restaurant"."id" AS "__col1" 
    FROM "restaurants_restaurant" 
    GROUP BY "restaurants_restaurant"."id") subquery
```

And instead django orm creates this little monstrosity:

```
    SELECT COUNT("__col1") 
    FROM (
        SELECT "restaurants_restaurant"."id" AS Col1,   "restaurants_restaurant"."id" AS "__col1" 
        FROM "restaurants_restaurant" 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments_comment" ON ("restaurants_restaurant"."id" = "comments_comment"."restaurant_id") 
        GROUP BY "restaurants_restaurant"."id", ST_Distance_Sphere("restaurants_restaurant"."location", 
                 ST_GeomFromEWKB('\x0101000020e61000003eb555a41d2d4b405a338d81d0a73240'::bytea
))) subquery
```

First method to be called is `get_list`. It looks as if django would "remember" that call and that the qs was annotated with `rating` and `distance` and places it also into the `count` query. So I guess the question is - how do I "reset" this queryset to the state before annotating it?

**EDIT:**

Okay, seems my question was not complete. I also have a `RestaurantsList` view defined as follows:

```
class RestaurantList(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Restaurant.objects.get_list(self._lng, self._lat)
```

I took a look into the entrails of django-rest-framework and I can see this:

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So it looks like it always uses the queryset that was returned from the `get_queryset` method and since it's annotated with `distance` and `rating` it ends up being included in the count query. Still no solution to this...

Comment: Stumbled across this one looking to optimize a paginated query with no where clause and heaps of select_related() items into a small query for count, small query for an initial list of ids, then the larger query with all the select_related using id__in on the. A custom paginator might get me closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing through django-rest-framework code I came up with this idea:

1. Override default `Paginator` class for a given view:

   ```
   class RestaurantList(generics.ListAPIView):
       pagination_class = custom.LimitOffsetPagination
   ```
2. Create custom pagination class:

   ```
   class LimitOffsetPagination(pagination.LimitOffsetPagination):
       def __init__(self):
           self._countable_queryset = None
           self._was_counted = False

       def was_initialized(self):
           return self._countable_queryset is not None

       def set_raw_queryset_for_count(self, queryset: QuerySet):
           self._countable_queryset = queryset

       def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
           self.limit = self.get_limit(request)
           if self.limit is None:
               return None
           self.offset = self.get_offset(request)
           self.count = self._countable_queryset.count()
           self.request = request
           if self.count > self.limit and self.template is not None:
               self.display_page_controls = True
           return list(queryset[self.offset:self.offset + self.limit])
   ```
3. Override views `paginator` property:

   ```
   @property
   def paginator(self):
       paginator = super().paginator
       if not paginator.was_initialized():
           paginator.set_raw_queryset_for_count(Restaurant.objects.all())
       return paginator
   ```

Now the count query will look a bit more friendly

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "restaurants_restaurant"
```